# How to deal with permission changes on a local client

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite, database-design, permissions

I built a SaaS system to allow multiple users to collaborate on a shared online database. A central server maintains the database. Users use their mobile device to login and access the data. Each mobile device has its own local copy of the database which is regularly updated: updates originates from the user device to the server (commit) if the user made some changes, other updates originates from the server (push update) when someone else made a commit.

Each database entry is identified by a global unique ID. Mobile clients can generate their database entries while being offline, because the IDs are generated randomly (128 bit random uuid). No central entity is required to assign the identifier, thus mobile clients can generate database entries at will while completely offline, without risking any ID collision with the rest of the data.

The system is very robust and fault tolerant: I designed the underlying REST API to be idempotent so repeated POST requests affect the database only once.

Now the big problem I'm facing:

Basically I'm just about to implement the biggest, much anticipated missing feature of the system: permissions.

Special admin users decide which user can see which database entry. It's a many-to-many relationship between users and entries so I added an extra table to encode the visibility flags:

**Table "userentry"**

```
+------------+------------------------------------------+
| user_id    | entry_id                                 |
+------------+------------------------------------------+
|         13 | b89eaac7e61417341b710b727768294d0e6a277b |
|         14 | bfd280436f45fa38eaacac3b00518f2961a44313 |
|         15 | e4fa1555ad877bf0ec455483371867200eee8955 |
|         15 | eb368a2dfd38b405f014118c7d9747fcc97f4f0e |
|         15 | bfd280436f45fa38eaacac3b00518f2932432443 |
+------------+------------------------------------------+
```

for example, user 13 can only access the entry "b89eaac...", user 14 only "bfd2804..." and user 15 the entries "e4fa155...", "eb368a2..." and "bfd280436..."

So far so good.

The problem is: at any given time the user's mobile device retain a full copy of the database. If an admin decides that user X can't see anymore the database entry Y, how can I reflect that on the local copy of the database?

I came up with a bunch of possible solutions, but none of them sound satisfactory to me:

**Solution no. 1 - just reflect the database on the local device as usual**

Basically I do what I've being doing so far: reflect the changes on the local copy of the database. The local copy of the access permission table "userentry" is reflected on the local database (after all, even that table is part of the database). The interface will show only the entries the user is allowed to access.

PROs: can't get any simpler to implement

CONs: unauthorized entries are actually stored on the local copy, all the times, even though the interface doesn't show them to the user

**Solution 2 - as solution 1, plus the server doesn't push unauthorized content**

Similarly to option 1, the local copy retains the permission table. This time though, the server doesn't push to the client the unauthorized content.

PROs: still quite simple to implement, just a minor check on the database before pushing stuff to the clients

CONs: can't safely revoke previously authorized contents (i.e. an admin user decide that user X can't see the content Y anymore: the content Y "disappears" from the interface but it's still on the local copy of the database)

**Solution 3 - as solution 2, plus actively delete unauthorized content still present on the local copy**

Same as solution 2 but this time any "leftover" entries are hard deleted from the local copy. Basically solution 3 implements the missing revoke functionality.

PROs: no unauthorized content is stored on the user device

CONs: sounds messy because we must hard delete entries on the local copy. What if the user has worked offline for a long time changing data he's not allowed to access anymore? The server will suddenly push a "delete" and user may risk losing some work.

**EDIT:**

IMHO The most sensible approach seems to be solution no.2 (don't push unauthorized stuff but also do not revoke local stuff). This is the rationale: If a user could access some entry in the past, does it really matter if that entry is still stored (albeit invisible) in the local copy of the db? Doesn't look like a security issue to me.

**EDIT:**

I could just give up the client "offline mode" feature, remove the concept of local database altogether and just let the clients operate through a REST API on the shared database. No more commits, no more push updates, instant permission updates. But I think is a little bit too late, as the users are well aware that they can use the client while offline, I can't just remove the feature anymore.

**EDIT:**

Please note that users share the database data within the same organization/company